# Matching three values (three cells) on a table

Tags: excel

I would like to know how this can be done with excel(if it can be done)? 
As you can see [in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P59ZT.png), I have a list of values (three cells in this case) to find and match in a list of data table, and if the values are present, 1 for yes and 0 for no output in the following column. So basically instead of one value in a single cell, I want to search and match three values in three cells on a table. (note:if you noticed, the values may not be present in adjacent cells on the table every time).

*** Groups of values should be on the same row to give a positive output of 1.

[image]

------Edited after the solution below----

```
=--(MAX((IF(MMULT((A2=$F$2:$I$6)*1,{1;1;1;1}),1,))+(IF(MMULT((B2=$F$2:$I$6)*1,{1;1;1;1}),1,))+(IF(MMULT((C2=$F$2:$I$6)*1,{1 ;1;1;1}),1,)))>=COUNTA(A2:C2))
```

Confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

You can replace {1;1;1;1} with TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($F$2:$I$2)^0). The IF and TRANSPOSE make the CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER necessary.

Comment: Please clarify your question - your data is ambiguous. What response do you want if there is a match for all elements? A match for 2 elements? A match for 1 element?

Comment: thanks. The data on the image is just an example to clarify what I need, there will be more data in actual table. I need a match for 3 values on the table.

Comment: So.... D3 should be 1, correct? Because 4,5, and 6 all appear in the list of data.

Comment: No, D3 should be 0 because the values (4,5,6) doesn't appear on the same row. We should consider them as a group, they should appear in the same row, and they may not be in the adjacent cells on the data table.

Comment: That is new information. Do the values also need to be beside eachother to work? Because in each of your matching examples, you have each result in order, starting with the first in column F. All of this is useful info, please edit your question to include all your required parameters. Make it easy for people to help you, and they will. - ed: I see you have added. Tx

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. yes the question was not clear. The values doesn't necessarily be in order, I just made this simple example fast and didn't pay much attention to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following as an example layout ...

[image: Excel]

... where range `F2:H4` contains your lookup array, columns `A,B,C` contain the values you are looking for, and column `D` contains the result, you can use the following formula in cell `D2` which can then be copied down to the rows below ...

```
=IF(IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$H$4,"="&A2) >0,1,0) + IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$H$4,"="&B2) >0,1,0) + IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$H$4,"="&C2) >0,1,0) = 3,1,0)
```

Examining `IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$H$4,"="&A2) >0,1,0)`, the `COUNTIF` expression counts all the occurrences of the value you are looking for (`A2` in this case), and then the `IF` expression converts any count > 1 to 1. When you apply this scheme across all three columns, if the sum of the nested `IF` statements is 3, then we have three matches ... one for each value you looked up.

---

In your case, the formula for D2 would be ...

```
=IF(IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$I$6,"="&A2) >0,1,0) + IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$I$6,"="&B2) >0,1,0) + IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$I$6,"="&C2) >0,1,0) = 3,1,0)
```

---

As @Grade 'Eh' Bacon mentions, this is a much cleaner formula ...

```
=MIN(1,COUNTIF($F$2:$I$6,A2),COUNTIF($F$2:$I$6,B2),COUNTIF($F$2:$I$6,C2))
```

---

[image]

Comment: Using the same principle you could shorten this significantly by replacing all of your IF functions with a single MIN function, like so: =MIN(1,countif($F$2:$I$6,A1)+countif($F$2:$I$6,B1)+countif($F$2:$I$6,C1)). This will show 0 if there are no matches, and will show 1 if there are any matches at all.

Comment: But it does if you change it to `=MIN(1,COUNTIF($F$2:$I$6,A2),COUNTIF($F$2:$I$6,B2),COUNTIF($F$2:$I$6,C2))` ... you needed the `,` instead of `+` separating the `COUNTIF`'s. I like it! :0)

Comment: If you do commas instead of +'s, then it will show 0 if any one of the values is 0 - I thought OP wanted it to show 1 if there were any matches, not if there was a match for all 3. That could be me misreading the question.

Comment: Even I'm not sure now! The second row in the example appears to have all the elements, and yet the formula returns 0! :O/

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake, yes it should be one. I missed that. but there is no formula. I made it as an example

Comment: So Pi's methodology is correct (either the one he has in his answer, or the one he wrote in the comment to his answer) - you should accept it as given.

Comment: @3-1415926535897932384  I tried these formulas on the image of the excel I provided, unfortunately it doesnt work. for example, even though there is (a,b,c), it gives 0 as output. and The values we look for can be in different columns and doesn't have to be adjacent cells.

Comment: @Max I've updated my answer with another image that shows it working! You must have a typo!

Comment: Just a note - this formula does not actually require that all values be on the same row. To do that is much more complex; I'm trying to work through an array formula but VBA may be required for that.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 sorry, but if it is not too much, can I ask what "3" stands for at the end of the formula?  ......+ IF(COUNTIF(G:J,"="&D5) >0,1,0)  = 3,1,0)

Comment: Yes you can ... each match counts as 1 so for all three matches, the total is 3. You should really use the formula that @Grade'Eh'Bacon came up with (added at the bottom of my answer) as it is much cleaner.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon you are right. it is not working exactly. the values should be on the same row.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264  sorry, I had to remove "accepting answer", both of the formulas do the same error. The values that match has to be on the same row of the table.

Comment: @Max a formula solution is not possible here without about 15 helper columns. This requires VBA to solve. Please attempt a VBA solution and someone here will take a look at it. Also, as Pi's approach solved your question as originally worded, you should leave his answer as accepted. You need to meet people halfway here.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon thanks. I will accept his solution. Should I repost this question again in VBA forum here?

Comment: Please post again as a VBA question, including the code that you have attempted to resolve. Indicate what areas are giving you difficulty.

Comment: For anybody viewing this in the future, this formula can be used:

`=--(MAX((IF(MMULT((A2=$F$2:$I$6)*1,{1;1;1;1}),1,))+(IF(MMULT((B2=$F$2:$I$6)*1,{1;1;1;1}),1,))+(IF(MMULT((C2=$F$2:$I$6)*1,{1 ;1;1;1}),1,)))>=COUNTA(A2:C2))` Confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

You can replace {1;1;1;1} with TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($F$2:$I$2)^0). The IF and TRANSPOSE make the CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER necessary.