# Data matching with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have certain values to find and match on a data table. http://jsfiddle.net/hhkd4ygu/
As you can see, there are 3 values and if any groups of 3 values are present altogether on a given ROW of the data table, the next row (present) should be highlighted; Green for present, Red color for not present.

Note: 3 values should be present on any row together and the values may not be in adjacent cells.

I've been trying to solve this problem on excel and did it with the help of a code I obtained from the VBA forum here. But I realized that running the vba code with a large data set is extremely slow and almost freezing my computer.

So I created a simple table to exemplify what I've been working on.

```css
.table.table {
 border: 1px solid #CCC; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: center;
 
} 
.table td {
 padding: 4px;
 margin: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 40px;
}
.table th {
 background-color: #E99D79; 
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.yes {
background: green;
}

.no {
background: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
<tr class="firstrow">
<th colspan="3">Values to find</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th><th> Presence</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th colspan="4">Data table</th></tr>

 <tr><td>1</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="yes"> </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>f</td><td>g</td><td>d</td><td>2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="yes">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>1</td><td>12</td><td>g</td><td>13</td></tr>
 <tr><td>a</td><td>b </td><td>c</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="yes">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>6</td></tr>
 <tr><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>f</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="no">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3</td><td>10</td><td>b</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="no">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>3</td><td>10</td><td>f</td><td>k</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

-------------------Edited after the answer provided below---

For future reference, for this kind of work, in addition to this, you may want to check excel+VBA solution (which is slow)=> [Matching multiple cell values on a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543167/matching-multiple-cell-values-on-a-table/31543875#31543875), 
and for excel only solution => [Matching three values (three cells) on a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537953/matching-three-values-three-cells-on-a-table/31538202?noredirect=1#comment51044119_31538202)  (see my last comment).

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: can it be done and how?

Comment: Sure, but you need to put in some effort and try to solve the problem first. We'll gladly help you if you get stuck, but we won't do all the work for you.

Comment: I don't understand your adjacency criterium.

Comment: @IARI for example on the first row of values 1,12,13 are present on the data table in this order : 1,12,g,13 => they are present in the same row but not in adjacent cells.

Comment: @j08691 thanks. I have some work done already but it is irrelevant to this problem. I think this is much more complex than a simple highlighting values on a data table which is not needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/hhkd4ygu/3/

In your example given, it acts as if *a, b, c* were present too.
However, considering your "not adjacent" criterium:

- if you only want triples to be present when they are found not adjacent, the code below is fine
- if you don't care about wether the found triples are adjacent, just remove the `&& (max-min >= 3)` part in the return statement of the match function.

code:

```
var trs = $('table').find('tr')

var gethtml = function () {
        return $(this).html()
    }
var rows = [];
trs.each(function () {
    var values = $(this).find('td').slice(6).map(gethtml).get();
    rows.push(values);
});

var match = function(row) {
    var ids = this.map(function(v){
        return row.indexOf(v);
    })
    var min = Math.min.apply(null,ids);
    var max = Math.max.apply(null,ids);
    return (min > -1) && (max-min >= 3);
}

trs.each(function () {
    var tds = $(this).find('td').slice(0,3);
    var values = $(this).find('td').slice(0,3).map(gethtml).get();

    var output = $(this).find('td').eq(4);
    var isMatch = rows.some(match.bind(values));
    output.addClass(isMatch ? 'yes' : 'no');
});
```

I can comment how it works if you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot @IARI it is working perfectly. I will update my question to give links to other types of solutions as well.  yes, I deleted that part, it is better for me.